# How to run a project made using google api 9 on emulator based on google api 8?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-manifest

I recently updated my google api's and installed lower versions of google api's.Now I'm having a project which I built using google api 9 but now I have an emulator based on google api 8.Can anyone tell me how to run such a project on that emulator ? What changed should I do for successful running of project ?

Answer (score 1):

You can still run your API 9 compiled application in your API 8 device emulator (as long as your code doesn't use things which are in 9 and not in 8). Else, create a new device emulator with API 9.